# ASP.NET Core User role enum value to Claim

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core-5.0

I have angular 12 front-end and ASP.NET Core 5 backend. I'm transferring the role through the JWT token. I want the role to be passed as an integer, so I don't hardcore the role name. The front-end itself will have an enum which will make it easier for me when there are checks like these horizontal menu settings are available for administrators only `if (user.role === Role.Administrator)`, etc.

The problem is that there is no such overload as `new("role", user.Role)`. If I do `user.Role.ToString()`, it sends `Administrator`, which is the key and not the value `1`.

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public enum Role
{
    Administrator = 1,
    DepartmentAdministrator = 2,
    User = 3
}

public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
    var user = _userRepository.FindById(sub);

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new("username", user.Username),
        new("email", user.Email),
        new("role", user.Role) // cannot be int
    };

    context.IssuedClaims = claims;

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the enum:

```
int role = (int) user.Role;

var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new("username", user.Username),
        new("email", user.Email),
        new("role", role.ToString())
    };
```

Comment: This post was a while a go, is there a way to create roles in token as integers and still reference the role in an authorization tag using a string, for example an enum name?